# How can I check the button which clicked is disabled with using protractor?

Tags: angular, testing, protractor, bdd, chai

I want to check the button is disabled after the button clicking, but disabled attribute is dynamic and I can't get the last state of the attribute:

Protractor:

```
const saveButton = element(by.id('saveButton'));

saveButton.click();
browser.sleep(1000);
await saveButton.isEnabled().then(enabled => {
    expect(enabled).to.be.false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="saveButton" [disabled]="isDisabled" mat-button (click)="saveArticle()">
    Save
</button>
```

Angular:

```
this.isDisabled = false;

saveArticle() {
    this.isDisabled = true;

    this.http.get('http://url').subscribe((response) => {
        this.isDisabled = false;
    });
}
```

Disabled attribute changes dynamically like above and this is not working properly. isEnabled() method always return true. How can I verify the button is disabled after clicking?

Comment: Are there any difference in the button attributes before and after clicking on it,? if so, you can just check the attribute value to be sure that button is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

are you using Jasmine matchers? if so, this should be enough:

```
const saveButton = element(by.id('saveButton'));

await saveButton.click();
browser.sleep(1000);
expect(await saveButton.isEnabled()).toBe(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use getAttribute('') and assert returned value. Notice that getAttribute might return null (if atribute has no value), or string